# Bar plot using mtcars

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to create a bar plot where x is represented by columns and y is represented by the value of mtcars. I have drawn an example for understanding.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(fill=mtcars[,1], y= ??? , x= mtcars[,mpg:carb])) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve. As I see in the drawing,there should be a bar stack for each column in the dataset, but what should the height of the stacked bars represent?

Comment: Yes, bar = column. The height is the value of each row and column, for example the first is 21.0 (cross mpg and Mazda RX4)

Comment: So each stack should consist of 32 bars, one for each car, right? Take a look at what ```barplot(as.matrix(mtcars))``` returns. Should it look like that?